# "var reloj" no recibe los estilos CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Cuando hago click en el botón de enviar mensaje, aparece la hora actualizada a la que ha sigo enviado el mensaje. Lo que no puedo es dar estilos a "var reloj" en "function sendMessage". Alguna solución? Gracias!!

Éste es mi código:

```js
var actualizarHora = function() {
  fecha = new Date(),
    horas = fecha.getHours(),
    minutos = fecha.getMinutes(),
    segundos = fecha.getSeconds(),
    dia = fecha.getDate(),
    mes = fecha.getMonth(),
    year = fecha.getFullYear(),


    phoras = document.getElementById("horas").innerHTML = horas,
    pminutos = document.getElementById("minutos").innerHTML = minutos,
    psegundos = document.getElementById("segundos").innerHTML = segundos,
    pdia = document.getElementById("dia").innerHTML = dia,
    pmes = document.getElementById("mes").innerHTML = mesesDelAño[mes],
    pyear = document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = year,


    pdia.innerHTML = dia,

    pmes.innerHTML = mesesDelAño[mes],

    pyear.innerHTML = year;

  if (phoras < 10) {
    phoras = "0" + phoras
  };
  if (pminutos < 10) {
    pminutos = "0" + pminutos
  };
  if (psegundos < 10) {
    psegundos = "0" + psegundos
  };

  phoras.innerHTML = horas;
  pminutos.innerHTML = minutos;
  psegundos.innerHTML = segundos;

};

actualizarHora();
var intervalo = setInterval(actualizarHora, 1000);

}())

function sendMessage() {

  var reloj = (" " + phoras + ":" + pminutos + ":" + psegundos + " | " + pdia + " de " + pmes + " del " + pyear);
}
```

```css
.tiempo {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #21c921;
}
```

```html
<div id="fecha_hora" class="fecha_hora">
  <p id="horas" class="tiempo"></p>
  <p class="tiempo">:</p>
  <p id="minutos" class="tiempo"></p>
  <p class="tiempo">:</p>
  <p id="segundos" class="tiempo"></p>
  <p class="tiempo"> | </p>
  <p id="dia" class="tiempo"></p>
  <p class="tiempo"> de </p>
  <p id="mes" class="tiempo"></p>
  <p class="tiempo"> del </p>
  <p id="year" class="tiempo"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Dar formato a `var reloj`? pero dar formato de que? a una variable no se le puede dar formato... a que te refieres con darle formato? (además que sendMessage no hace nada con esa variable)

Comment: La variable reloj solo es un texto, para poder aplicarle estilos tendrías que poner esa variable en el HTML con innerHTML y ahí recién aplicarle el CSS a la etiqueta que lo contenga.

Comment: Hola! Lo que quería decir es que el contenido de "var reloj" (phoras, pminutos, psegundos...) no coge el formato de los estilos css, cuando aparecen en el dom con clase "tiempo" y uso innerHTML para cambiar su contenido. Alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: Hola! Lo que quería decir es que el contenido de "var reloj" (phoras, pminutos, psegundos...) no coge el formato de los estilos css, cuando aparecen en el dom con clase "tiempo" y uso innerHTML para cambiar su contenido. Alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: La verdad es que no entiendo o no explicas bien al elemento que quieres darle estilos al ejecutar la función sendMessage. De todas formas, puedes usar el getelementbyid con el id del elemento que quieres aplicar estilos y añadirle los estilos directamente con la propiedad style o añadir una clase con la propiedad classList.Add("tiempo").